# Problem connecting Postman with Apache Drill with MySQL

Tags: rest, postman, apache-drill

**I have installed apache drill and it is working fine. I am trying to fetch data from MYSQL table in postman REST APi**

1. localhost:8047/query.json - launching properly
2. mysqlplugin configured successfully
3. From drill command line, MYSQL command working properly

   ```
   apache drill> SELECT * FROM mysqlplugin.test.`table` LIMIT 10;
    +----+-------+
    | id | name  |
    +----+-------+
    | 1  | anil  |
    | 2  | amit  |
    | 3  | ankur |
   ```

But when I connect REST API to localhost:8047/query.json
using body:

```
{
"queryType" : "SQL",
"query" : "select * from mysqlplugin.test.`table`;"
}
```

It gives response:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: 405 means you're using wrong method for request? for example. it requires `POST`, but you use `GET`

Comment: Thanks. Yes that I oversighted.. it should be POST. It worked.. Another thing is that semicolumn should not be in the query

Comment: Also there is a typo in the params.  It should be `queryType` not `queryype`.

Comment: yes, thanks, corrected in question.